# Save and Rounding the range in TimeField Formset in Views Django

Tags: django

I have following code to save and rounding the range of TimeField in Views Django:

```
begin1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('01:00', '%H:%M').time()
end1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('02:00', '%H:%M').time()
begin2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('02:00', '%H:%M').time()
end2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('03:00', '%H:%M').time()

import datetime

if formset.is_valid():
    for item in formset:
        if formset.mytime > begin1 and formset.mytime < end1:
#           formset.mytime = item.cleaned_data['mytime']
            formset.mytime = '01:00'
        if formset.mytime > begin2 and formset.mytime < end2:
#           formset.mytime = item.cleaned_data['mytime']
            formset.mytime = '02:00'
            formset.save()
```

So for example, if user input the mytime: 01:52 then rounding to the lowest hour and would save as 01:00.
But it wouldn't save to the database. What's the wrong with above code?
Thank in advanced for your help.

Comment: Your `formset.save()` is nested under the second `if`.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. There is an error in my code. Thanks @urbanespaceman